# How to get the lat lng or position of a marker that is placed in googlemaps v2 and make a clickable link to googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, gps, location, google-maps-markers

My code is as follows:

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            // Get marker latLng

            marker.getPosition();

         Context context = getApplicationContext();

            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); 

                    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                    setLatitude();
                    setLongitude();

                    i.setType("text/plain");

                            + "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat + "," + lng   );
```

In the link that is created I get this (  [http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:null,null](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc%3anull,null)   )

Why do I get null for lat and lng in text link.?

I have declared doubles for lat and lng at the head of the class.

The marker.getPosition(); should return a postion or pair of lat lng.

I can see that position in the info window.

Thanks for any help

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "lat" and "lng" variable are not declared nor instantiated.

This is the way to set them:

```
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: can you show me to do this way exactly  I have problem

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: Great insight ! issue is solved.  Thanks to you Sir, and all who cared enough to view my problem.

Comment: I worked on your comment and it was right on the spot.I am new to android and this forum and I appreciate your taking the time to help. what great insight. How can or can I vote for you? I don't know.

Comment: Glad I could help!
You can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left of my message.